# Is IBM MobileFirst a longlife solution?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm searching for crossplatforms to develop mobile applications but the main criteria is the app's longevity. By longevity I mean if there is/will be updates by the company regularly and if the platform won't be give up without any updates from the company. The platform I discovered that suits a bit for what I'd like to do is: IBM Mobilefirst.

I just discovered it and didn't have time to search more about it. According to you, is it a longlife solution?
I take the opportunity to ask also if there is any license price or not. I have downloaded the platform from Eclipse but will I have to pay for something later?

Comment: Apparently is not free: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030963/ibm-worklight-license-is-worklight-free-to-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform is a product by IBM. While I work there, my personal opinion is that this platform is not going anywhere ("get ditched") anytime soon, rather the opposite - there is a lot going forward.

Eclipse is used as the development environment. It is comprised of a plug-in that you install. You are not required to use Eclipse, as there is also a command-line interface provided, so you can use any other tool that you prefer...

The developer edition is the full release (not hindered in any way) and you can use it to develop your applications for free.

The licensing comes in when you want to move to production.
For pricing you should contact IBM.

You can read more as well as find contact information @ the MobileFirst Plaform Developer Center website: http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform